# How to execute the gulp command after going into a particular directory with git bash using bat file?

Tags: git, bash, batch-file, cmd, git-bash

This is a the bat file I am currently executing. It does open the git bash in a particular folder, but does not execute the gulp command on the git bash command line. How can I do that?

`C:
cd C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\gulp-dev
start "" "%PROGRAMFILES%\Git\bin\sh.exe"  --login`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, instead of `C:`, replace the first two lines with:

```
cd /d C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\gulp-dev
```

`/d` will change drive if necessary.

Second, add:

```
start /b "%cd%" "%PROGRAMFILES%\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login
```

Third, if you want to [execute a command on shell opening](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5203890/6309):

```
...sh.exe" --login -i -c "my command"
```